# Plotting variables after some operation in ggplot2 - more a question of style

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently familiarizing myself with ggplot2 and I here have a question related more to coding style.

I started with this, which throws an error:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x[-1], diff(y))) + geom_point()
```

I can achieve what I want with this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
new_dat <- data.frame(x = dat$x[-1], y_diff = diff(dat$y))
ggplot(data = new_dat, aes(x, y_diff)) + geom_point()
```

However, I am wondering if there is a more direct / elegant way. In particular, I am wondering if ggplot2 allows to do calculations / subsetting on the variables inside the `ggplot` call. If not - that's ok and I can live with the detour - if yes great!

I could not find anything related to this on google or in the ggplot2 manual (https://ggplot2-book.org/index.html)

Thanks a lot in advance and best greetings,
Sebastian

Comment: While in general you could do operations on the variables, your case is special in that it changes the dimensions of the data, i.e. you drop one row. Hence you get an error `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): x and y`. TBMK in this case you have to do the operation on the data, e.g. `ggplot(data = dat |> dplyr::summarise(x = x[-1], y = diff(y)), aes(x, y)) + geom_point()` will work.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks!
This works, but is also a bit more unwieldy than in 'base' R.

Comment: How about: `ggplot(dat, aes(x, y - dplyr::lag(y))) + geom_point()`